# Mean of order p of two numbers an increasing sequence

Tags: analysis, limits

Define the mean of order $p$ of $a$ and $b$ as $s_p(a,b)$ $=$ $({a^p + b^p\over 2})^{1/p}$.

I have to find the limit of the sequence $s_n(a,b)$. I already know this sequence is bounded above by $b$ (from a previous question) and if I assume the limit exists I can show it is $b$. What I cannot show is that the sequence is increasing. Could someone assist me or show me how to prove this?

Comment: maybe you can just show the convergence without the monotonic convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the squeeze theorem. Supposing $b>a\ge 0$:
$$\frac b{2^{1/p}}=\left(\frac{b^p}2\right)^{1/p}\le\left(\frac{a^p + b^p}2\right)^{1/p}
\le\left(\frac{b^p + b^p}2\right)^{1/p}=b
$$
ant take $\lim_{p\to\infty}$.

Comment: Thanks. I actually did something similar to this to show the limit was b -assuming it was higher; something I forgot to mention in the initial post- but I forgot that by the hypothesis of the squeeze theorem it was actually sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for increasing:

let us assume that $b>a\ge 0$, that is $a = b-r$, $r>0$.

Then $$
\left( \frac{a^p + b^p}2
\right)^{1/p}=
b \left( \frac 12 \left[\left(\frac{b-r}b \right)^p + 1
\right]\right)^{1/p}=
b\left[\frac 12\right]^{1/p} \left[\left(\frac{b-r}b \right)^p + 1
\right]^{1/p}
$$
now $\left[\frac 12\right]^{1/p}\to 1$ and
$$
\frac 1p\log\left[\left(\frac{b-r}b \right)^p + 1
\right]\sim \frac 1p\left[\left(\frac{b-r}b \right)^p\right]\to 0
$$
Now use the continuity of the exponential to get $$
\left[\left(\frac{b-r}b \right)^p + 1
\right]^{1/p} \to 1\\
\left( \frac{a^p + b^p}2
\right)^{1/p}\to b
$$

Answer (score 0):

Remark that for two positive numbers $a$ and $b$, $a^p+ b^p \underset{+ \infty}{\sim} max(a,b)^p$.
It should be helpful to answer the question